# How can I get the top 20 distinct values in a column in R

Tags: r, filter, group-by

I have just begun learning R and I am stuck with a problem that I cannot seem to find a solution to.

The scenario.

- **data frame** - trips
- **column** - users *(2 values, 3 million+ observations)*
- **column** - stations *(650 values, 3 million+ observations)*

What I want is the top 20 stations by usage for the two user types. I apologize if my articulation of the problem is inappropriate.

**For example:**

```
stations <- c("stn1","stn1" ,"stn2", "stn3", "stn3", "stn1", "stn2" )

users <- c("member", "member", "user", "member", "user", "user","user")

trips = data.frame(stations, users)

trips

table(trips)
```

What should I do if I want to know the most used station by a member & user respectively and also the number of time it was used in descending order and only limited to 20.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
trips %>%
   group_by(stations) %>%
   mutate(n = n_distinct(users)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   slice_max(n, n = 20, with_ties = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer.  I used it and then someone else suggested some changes, the final version that i used and that works well for me is:                                                             top_stations_by_usertype <- trips %>%
  group_by(users, stations) %>%
  summarise(rides = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(rides)) %>%
  top_n(10, rides)